# snackbar with custom Function call in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, snackbar

I am using snackBar in my app, it's working fine in my application but I want to access the Custom Function from SnackBar Action Block.

I can try that it's showing

- Instance member 'uncheck' cannot be used on type 'DetailsInfoViewController' did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

This is the code

```
let snackbar = TTGSnackbar(message: "Attendance Update !",
                           duration: .long,
                           actionText: "SEND",

                           actionBlock: {
                                (snackbar) in

                            uncheck()

                            print("snack bar Action")

})

func uncheck()
{

    print("snackbar uncheck function")
    snackbarCount -= 1
    checkSnackBar()
}
```

How can I access the custom function in snack Bar actionBlock inside?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: just add self.uncheck() inside the block as it's a block

Comment: I added self.uncheck() in side block getting this Error (Value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> DetailsInfoViewController' has no member 'uncheck)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you've initialized `snackbar` inside a `class func` or something like that. From this place `self` represents your class `DetailsInfoViewController` while you need the object of this class. If you initialize this object before `snackbar`, you could write like this:

```
let controller: DetailsInfoViewController = ...
let snackbar = TTGSnackbar(message: "Attendance Update !", duration: .long, actionText: "SEND") { [weak controller] (snackbar) in
    controller?.uncheck()
    print("snack bar Action")
}
```

If it doesn't help you, please post the function code where you're creating `snackbar`.

**UPD:**
With minimal changes of your code the following solution should work:

```
class DetailsInfoViewController: UIViewController {

    var snackbarCount = 0

    lazy var snackbar = TTGSnackbar(message: "Attendance Update !", duration: .long, actionText: "SEND") { (snackbar) in
        self.uncheck()
        print("snack bar Action")
    }

    func uncheck() {
        print("snackbar uncheck function")
        snackbarCount -= 1
        checkSnackBar()
    }

    func checkSnackBar() {}

}
```

You found really tricky situation when your class requires `self` inside closure as it initializes **but** this `snackbar` variable initializes before we have ready-to-use `self` variable. It means we need to initialize `snackbar` after `self` using `lazy var`.

But I **strongly** suggests you to not write code as you wrote it. The [TTHSnackbar author's example](https://github.com/zekunyan/TTGSnackbar#show-a-simple-message-with-an-action-button) is designed to be placed in a function when this snackbar really need to be shown. For example:

```
class DetailsInfoViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func showSnackbarButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let snackbar = TTGSnackbar(message: "TTGSnackBar !", duration: .middle, actionText: "Action!") { (snackbar) in
            self.uncheck()
            print("snack bar Action")
        }
        snackbar.show()
    }

}
```

When it shows on the view it will be retained by this view.

**UPD #2**:
To show only one Snackbar at a time you could write like this:

```
class DetailsInfoViewController: UIViewController {

    private weak var currentSnackbar: TTGSnackbar?

    @IBAction func showSnackbarButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let snackbar = currentSnackbar {
            snackbar.dismiss()
            currentSnackbar = nil
        }

        let snackbar = TTGSnackbar(message: "TTGSnackBar !", duration: .middle, actionText: "Action!") { (snackbar) in
            self.uncheck()
            print("snack bar Action")
        }

        currentSnackbar = snackbar
        snackbar.show()
    }

}
```

Comment: function code                                                                                           class DetailsInfoViewController:  {   
    let snackbar = TTGSnackbar(message: "Attendance Update !",
  duration: .long,
 actionText: "SEND",
  actionBlock: {
                                (snackbar) in
                                uncheck()      
   print("snack bar Action")           
    }) inside same class I'm calling func uncheck() function  func uncheck()
{

    print("snackbar uncheck function")
    snackbarCount -= 1
    checkSnackBar()
}

Comment: lazy var snackbar = TTGSnackbar(message: "Attendance Update !", duration: .long, actionText: "SEND") { (snackbar) in
        self.uncheck()
        print("snack bar Action")
    } this can working fine thanks bro

Comment: I'm using multiple check boxes in tableview  I can try this one but multiple snack bars showing in table view @IBAction func showSnackbarButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let snackbar = TTGSnackbar(message: "TTGSnackBar !", duration: .middle, actionText: "Action!") { (snackbar) in
            self.uncheck()
            print("snack bar Action")
        }
        snackbar.show()
    }

Comment: @nagarajukankanala, it could be done by keeping the weak reference to the last snackbar shown and hiding it before presenting a new one. I updated the answer to show it.