# What is the equivalent of a SnackBar in Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm porting an Android application to iOS. Part of the user-interface is an Android Snackbar; a small box at the bottom of the screen alerting the user of something, while not being a full-fledged dialog:

[image: SnackBar image]

I tried different methods of the built-in UIAlertView from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988564/how-to-implement-a-pop-up-dialog-box-in-ios) but there was nothing alike. Is this even possible with Swift and what are the best frameworks for Snackbar imitation?

Comment: Similar 3rd party lib: https://github.com/zekunyan/TTGSnackbar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [snackbar with custom Function call in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012358/snackbar-with-custom-function-call-in-swift)

Comment: It's because your question is too general and broad - which means someone probably has asked this before, and yeah, a lot have. You should ask only when there is no question on SOF that can answer you ;)

Comment: You can display a notification instead of showing a snackbar.

Comment: @acmpo6ou Out of curiosity, what do you mean? A notification is "outside" of the app (handled by the OS, triggered by the app), whereas the snackbar is "inside" the app's UI.

Comment: For SwiftUI I have created below utility.

https://github.com/indrajitv/ICToastMessage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SnackBar (along with Toast, PopupDialog, etc.) is a concept baked into Android, and there's no equivalent on iOS.

You can:

- create a custom component, and handle fly-in and fly-out animations, or,
- use external libraries. My go-to is [ahmedAlmasri's SnackBar.swift](https://github.com/ahmedAlmasri/SnackBar.swift), which resembles a lot of that on Android.